# Unknown android app using my mp3 files without my permission

Tags: android, web, service, mp3, hotlinking

I have found an app on play store using my absolute path of mp3 files to his/her app to stream my mp3 files. I think he/she created a script which crawling my website and getting mp3 files with title of the songs or albums and then creating his/her database and then creating a web service which generates json. So he/she can use it in app. I have tried to prevent hotlinking of mp3 files from my .htaccess from my server but i think this trick is only working for websites not working for android applications. Please tell me how to stop mp3 files from third parties android apps or any other platforms except my own app. I have my own app on android so i don't need to stop that too. Thanks
Waiting for solution from experts :)

Comment: keep some authentication token in app to identify the service is called from your app.

Comment: dear they just pulling my website absolute path like https://example.com/somefolder/mp3fils/name.mp3 to play the mp3 file in their player on android app. how to prevent them from accessing my mp3 files , what should i do on my whm or htaccess file

Comment: do you tried symlink  method ?

Answer (score 0):

tahir issue is very simple. when some one wants to access your mp3 file ask app secret key in web service call . for sure now you will authenticate service no spams calls

Comment: the person is not calling my services he made a script which crawls to my whole website from where he getting all possible information like, song_id, song_title and the absolute path of the mp3 files then after this he is storing all info in his database and then he creating his own services file on his host. I think  i need to block mp3 file access to un authorised users in android apps, i can do it in websites but i think in android or other apps its not working. i have created .htaccess file to block hotlinking but its not working in apps thanks!